# Is this a Boolean Algebra Theorem/Law?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I just wanted to ask if this law is correct?

(X'+Y)(X+Z) = X'Z + XY

I saw it from this picture

number 16
http://image.slidesharecdn.com/booleanalgebralaws-121126060037-phpapp02/95/boolean-algebra-laws-1-638.jpg?cb=1353931281

And When I foil it out, this is what I get.

(X'+Y)(X+Z) = X'X + X'Z + XY + YZ

= X'Z + XY + YZ

Which does not equal the law above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my answer:

These equations are equivalent:

```
(X'+Y)(X+Z) = X'Z + XY
X'X + X'Z + XY + YZ = X'Z + XY     (expand left hand)
X'Z + XY + YZ = X'Z + XY           (X'X = 0 always)
X'Z + XY = X'Z + XY                (YZ => X'Z + XY)
```

The last step can be seen like this. There are two possibilities:

1. *YZ=1*

   Then both *Y=1* and *Z=1*, and then the right hand of the equation is also 1 (given that at least *X=1* or *X'=1*).
2. *YZ=0*

   The term can thus be removed from the equation, and then both hands are equal.

NB: you might get better replies on [maths.exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for these types of questions.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I would still be left with X'Z + XY + YZ. Im stuck at that step :(

Comment: On both sides of the equation. If both sides are the same, then you have a truth, right?

Comment: I may have formatted my question wrong. Im trying to achieve the very first equation but i get an extra YZ on mine, when I expand it.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the first version of the question: I updated my answer.